# Creation of generic type relying on another type C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, sortedlist

I have a class which is defined as

```
public class SerializableList<TList, TValue> : IXmlSerializable where TList : IList<TValue>
```

The issue comes when trying to implement the constructor to make sure I have a TList object.

```
public SerializableList()
{
    FList = new TList();
}
```

Which throws the expected error of not having a new() constraint. As I want to be able to use the definition of

```
var myList = new SerializableList<SortedList<string>, string>();
```

does this mean I have looking at things the wrong way, or is there a way I can define the new FList object?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get that. What prevents you from writing `public class SerializableList<TList, TValue> : IXmlSerializable where TList : IList<TValue>, new ()` ?

Comment: What is the question here? If you want to new and compiler says new constraint is missing then you can simply add the new constraint...

Comment: Thought I tried new() and it caused an issue with using list<t>. It doesn't so I have asked for the question to be deleted. Sorry wasting time if I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SerializableList<TList, TValue> : IXmlSerializable
    where TList : IList<TValue>, new()
```

Comment: Yep, thought I tried this and it didn't work. Think I will delete this question.

Comment: @Jason What do you mean by "it didn't work"? It didn't compile? It threw an exception?

Comment: The "error" that I saw must not have been related to the addition of new() to the declaration of SerializableList. What you have suggested works exactly as required. Basically a mess up on my part when I tried it before asking the question, or something a clean rebuild fixed along the way. Have asked for the question to be deleted as it will confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are [Generic Type Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

In your instance the class declaration needs to be

```
public class SerializableList<TList, TValue> 
    : IXmlSerializable where TList : IList<TValue>, new()
```

Where `new()` enforces that `TList` must have a parameterless constructor